# LinkedIn Android SDK set up

Tags: android, linkedin-api, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I have started integrating LinkedIn log in to my app by following the Getting Started guide provided by developer.linkedin.com

I have downloaded the mobile SDK for Android and imported the linkedin-sdk in my project.

Added the following line to my dependencies in build.gradle:

```
compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
```

Added the following line in my settings.gradle:

```
include ':linkedin-sdk'
```

When I sync the project I get the following error:

```
Error:(8, 0) Plugin with id 'robolectric' not found.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried syncing with the robolectric manually in gradle? testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0"

Comment: @ProkashSarkar the linkedin-sdk has this in the gradle already:     androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') ... I tried 3.0 but still same error as before

Comment: Interesting, the plugin was deprecated. I would ask linkedin team to fix library and even better to distribute library through binary dependency instead of sources

Answer (score 1):

As quick solution please remove next lines from `linked-sdk` `build.gradle` files:

```
buildscript {
   ...
   dependencies {
     classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.14.+'
   }
}

apply plugin: 'robolectric'
```

And these as well just to be 100% sure:

```
androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4')
```

I hope you're also aware that you include `volley` into your app. So you might experience duplicate class error while dexing

Comment: This worked but it's not very elegant. Thanks a lot for the input, however! Like you said, I already had volley in my project so what I did was I removed the volley.jar from the linkedin-sdk and changed the linkedin-sdk gradle to     compile files(':libs/volley.jar')

Comment: Ask Linkedin guys to fix it :)